# Doxygen not documenting global function when SHOW_FILES == NO

Tags: doxygen

I have a static function defined right in the header file, which I am trying to document. By reading related questions I figured out the following:

- `\file` section in the beginning of the file must present
- `EXTRACT_STATIC` must be set to yes

If I set `SHOW_FILES = YES`, the documentation for my function is generated, but I do not want to generate the files page. So my question: is it possible to generate documentation for a global function when `SHOW_FILES == NO`?

Comment: I think the answer is no, the definition must be housed in some page, and if the file page is not available then there is nowhere to put it. What is the reason you don't want the files page? You can disable including the source with VERBATIM_HEADERS = NO

Comment: @Artur Kink If I have a class that is defined in a header, then class documentation will be generated even when the file page is not available. Why doesn't this work the same way for global functions? Maybe there exist a way to house these functions somewhere if the files page is the only default location?